# ServiceStack.Redis Unknown Reply on Integer response and Zero Length Response

Tags: .net, redis, servicestack

I am running into errors using ServiceStack's Redis client in production.

The error is "Unknown reply on integer response: 43OK" for **RedisClient.ContainsKey** and "Zero length response" for **RedisClient.Get**.

The application uses Redis Sentinel and PoolRedisClientManager. I have wrapper class to initialize Redis instance with along with Redis operations:

```
      public class RedisFactory : IRedisFactory
      {
        private RedisSentinel redisSentinel;
        private IRedisClientsManager clientsManager;

        public void Init()
        {
        RedisConfig.DefaultRetryTimeout = RETRY_TIMEOUT; //5000ms
        RedisClientManagerConfig config = new RedisClientManagerConfig()
        {
            MaxReadPoolSize = MAX_POOL_SIZE, //40
            MaxWritePoolSize = MAX_POOL_SIZE, //40
            DefaultDb = DEFAUTL_DB
        };

        redisSentinel = new RedisSentinel(sentinelHosts, masterName: masterName)
        {
            RedisManagerFactory = (master, slaves) => new PooledRedisClientManager(master.ToList(), slaves.ToList(), config)
            {
                NamespacePrefix = NAMESPACE_PREFIX
            },
            OnFailover = manager => _log.Info($"Fail over at {DateTime.Now}"),
            OnWorkerError = ex => _log.Error($"Sentinel worker error \n {ex}"),
            OnSentinelMessageReceived = (channel, msg) => _log.Info($"Received '{channel}' on channel '{msg}' from Sentinel")

        };

        clientsManager = redisSentinel.Start();
    }

    public bool KeyExisted(string key)
    {
        Func<string, bool> keyExisted = delegate (string k)
        {
            using (var slave = clientsManager.GetReadonlyClient())
            {
                var existed = slave.ContainsKey(k);
                return existed;
            }
        };

        return Execute(nameof(keyExisted), key, keyExisted);
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        Func<string, T> get = delegate (string k)
        {
            using (var slave = clientsManager.GetReadonlyClient())
            {
                var value = slave.Get<T>(k);
                return value;
            }
        };

        return Execute(nameof(get), key, get);
    }

    private T Execute<T>(string operation, string key, Func<string, T> func)
    {
        int retry = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return func(key);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error($"Redis operation: {operation} error \n {ex}");

                if (ex is RedisException)
                {
                    if (retry >= 3) 
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                    retry++;

                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The wrapper is registered as a singleton instance in AppHost

```
    public class AppHost : AppHostBase { public override void Configure(Container container){

    var redisFactory = new RedisFactory
    {
        MaxPoolSize = AppSettings.Get("MaxPoolSize", 40),
        MaxRetryAttempts = AppSettings.Get("MaxRetryAttempts", 3),
        RetryTimeout = AppSettings.Get("RetryTimeout", 5000),
        NameSpacePrefix = AppSettings.GetString("NameSpacePrefix"),
        DefaultDB = 13
    };  redisFactory.Init(); container.Register<IRedisFactory>(redisFactory);}}
```

Redis Factory usage

```
    public class MyService
    {
        private IRedisFactory cacheClient = HostContext.TryResolve<IRedisFactory>();    

        public object SomeMethod(string key) => cacheClient.Get<object>(key);
    }
```

I have a retry function as in RedisFactory::Execute. I notice that the first attempt will throw exceptions as below, but the second attempt will be successful.

```
ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException: Unknown reply on integer response: 43OK
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.ReadLong()
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendReceive[T](Byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs, Func`1 fn, Action`1 completePipelineFn, Boolean sendWithoutRead)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendExpectLong(Byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.ContainsKey(String key)
   at RedisLibrary.RedisFactory.<KeyExisted>b__30_0(String k)



 ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException: Zero length response
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.ParseSingleLine(String r)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendReceive[T](Byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs, Func`1 fn, Action`1 completePipelineFn, Boolean sendWithoutRead)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendExpectData(Byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.<>c__DisplayClass131_0`1.<Get>b__0(RedisClient r)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.Exec[T](Func`2 action)
   at RedisLibrary.RedisFactory.<Get>b__31_0[T](String k)
```

And this is happening only with ContainsKey and Get operation. Add, Remove or replace is still working normally.

An important thing to note that these errors has been found in production since we changed Redis Server configuration as below:

// Redis server configuration changes

```
  Fail over – timeout redis -cluster 5000 ->15000

  Tcp-keepalive 0 ->300

  Repl -blacklog-size 10mb -> 50mb
```

I tried to reproduce the issue in test environment with same Redis configuration as in production but failed. I have been also looking for other similar problems such as sharing same Redis client in [ServiceStack.Redis Client Unknown reply on integer response: 430k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476382/servicestack-redis-client-unknown-reply-on-integer-response-430k) but nothing helps.

Could anyone help me point out what is wrong with my implementation or Redis configuration? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have a look at [Debugging data corruption issues](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#debugging-data-corruption-issues) for tips for diagnosing invalid responses. BTW you should avoid deserializing into unknown types like `Get<object>`. Use the Type if you know it, if you don't, but know it's an object you can deserialize into a generic collection like `Get<Dictionary<string,string>>`.

Comment: Sorry that it's just my sample code. My real code uses known type in get operation